# Rails 3.2.13 - Session gets cleared using a disabled HTML form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, session, hash

I am having a problem with the session hash getting cleared out upon form submission and cannot figure out why this is the case. Here's the situation:

I have a few models in my application, one of which is called a **Plan**. Users can view, edit, delete, or create a plan. When any of the actions except view are invoked, a form appears, and the user can dynamically add information to the plan and ultimately submit the form to create/update the plan in a database. An output is also generated based on the user's inputs. This part works fine.

The issue occurs when I am working with a disabled form. The **show** action is invoked when the user clicks to view the existing plan. On the view mode, the form is essentially read-only, so I have disabled all of the form's elements except the Submit button. Originally, the form wasn't read-only, and when it wasn't, I had no issues whatsoever. The user would be able to view the plan and click the Submit button to get the correct output.

Now, with a disabled form, the user can perform the same process, except it is evident that the form's information cannot be modified. When the user goes to click on the same Submit button, the form is processed, but the output does not get rendered at all.

After much troubleshooting, I've managed to figure out that the session hash is being cleared for some reason, resulting in some of the logic not working properly. The **show** action is called when the user clicks to view the plan, and when the Submit button is clicked, the **render_plan** action is called next. I do not have any before_filters for the **render_plan** action. In the **show** action, I set **session[:accessType]** to **"View."** I've verified that the hash actually gets set. Now, when it moves onto the **render_plan** action, I've checked the session hash, and it is completely cleared out. I cannot seem to figure out why and have been trying to for hours.

Again, everything works fine when the form is not disabled. I do not need any of the information from the form when it is submitted in the read-only mode because I use all of the database's stored information for the plan as opposed to the submitted information. Also, I've verified that there are no syntax/runtime errors in my code.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the session hash is being cleared out? I am not clearing it out in any way. Thanks in advance for any help!

---

**EDIT #1**

My 'show' html.erb file which contains the form can be found below:

```
<% if session[:accessType] != "Create" %>
    <% provide(:title, @savedPlan.name) %>

    <h1 id="pagetitle"><%= session[:accessType] %>ing: <%= @savedPlan.name %></h1>
<% else %>
    <% provide(:title, 'New Project Plan') %>

    <h1 id="pagetitle">New Project Plan</h1>
<% end %>

<div id="form_errors">
    <ul>
        <li>Please correct the errors below:</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<h2 class="sectiontitle">Choose the project mode.</h2>

<%# Sets the correct project mode for the saved project plan %>
<% if !@savedPlan.nil? %>
    <% if @savedPlan.projectMode == "variable" %>
        <% varChecked = 'checked=checked' %>
    <% else %>
        <% fixedChecked = 'checked=checked' %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <% varChecked = 'checked=checked' %>
<% end %>

<label class="radio inline radiolabel">
    <input id="radVar" name="radMode" type="radio" value="Variable" tabindex="1" <%= if !varChecked.nil?; varChecked; end %>
           onclick="OptionChoice();"> 
    Variable
</label>

<label id="lblRadFixed" class="radio inline radiolabel">
    <input id="radFixed" name="radMode" type="radio" value="Fixed" tabindex="2" <%= if !fixedChecked.nil?; fixedChecked; end %>
           onclick="OptionChoice();">
    Fixed
</label>

<div class="variable projectmode">
    <%= form_tag({:controller => 'project_plans', :action => 'render_plan' },
                 { :multipart => true, :id => 'frmvariableplan', :name => 'frmvariableplan', :class => 'form-inline' }) do %>
        <input id="variable_project_mode" name="projectmode" value="variable" type="hidden">

        <div class="row proj-start-end-date-div">
            <div class="span4">
                <%= label_tag :projname, "Project Name", :class => 'project_date_label biglbl biglbl-spacing' %>
                <input class="proj-start-end-date input-spacing" name="projname" type="text" value="<%= if !@savedPlan.nil?; @savedPlan.name; end %>">
            </div>

            <div class="span4">
                <%= label_tag :projstartdate, "Start Date", :class => 'project_date_label biglbl biglbl-spacing' %>
                <input class="proj-start-end-date input-spacing datepicker read_only_input" name="projstartdate" type="text"
                       value="<%= if !@savedPlan.nil?; @savedPlan.startDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"); end %>" readonly="true">
            </div>

            <div class="span4">
                <%= label_tag :projenddate, "End Date", :class => 'project_date_label biglbl biglbl-spacing' %>
                <input class="proj-start-end-date" name="projenddate" type="text"
                       value="<%= if !@savedPlan.nil?; @savedPlan.endDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"); end %>" readonly="true">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Horizontal Rule to break the page up into sections -->
        <hr />

        <div>
            <!-- Simple service type -->
            <label name="lblServiceType_Simple" class="biglbl servicetypeheading">Service Type: Simple</label>

            <div id="divServiceType_Simple" class="servicetypediv">
                <%= render :partial => 'project_plans/display_services', :locals => { :type_service => 'simple' } %>

                <%= render :partial => 'project_plans/add_service', :locals => { :service_type => 'simple' } %>

                <% if !@savedPlan.nil? %>
                    <% service_array_length = (@all_services_array[0].count - 1) %>                     

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        <% if (service_array_length >= 0) %>
                            CreateSlider("simple", "Total",   0, 144, <%= @all_services_array[0][0].totalHours %>);
                            CreateSlider("simple", "Design",  0, 64,  <%= @all_services_array[0][0].designHours %>);
                            CreateSlider("simple", "Develop", 0, 80,  <%= @all_services_array[0][0].developHours %>);
                        <% else %>                      
                            CreateSlider("simple", "Total",   0, 144, 144);
                            CreateSlider("simple", "Design",  0, 64,  64);
                            CreateSlider("simple", "Develop", 0, 80,  80);
                        <% end %>
                    </script>

                    <% (0..service_array_length).each do |i| %>
                        <% service = @all_services_array[0][i] %>

                        <%= render(:partial => 'project_plans/new_service',
                                   :locals => { :type_service => 'simple', :type_count => (i + 1),
                                                :service_name => service.name, :start_date => service.startDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
                                                :end_date => service.endDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
                                                :design_endDate => service.design_endDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), :priority => service.priority,
                                                :should_display_button => ((i != service_array_length) ? 'false' : 'true') }) %>
                    <% end %>

                    <% session[:simple] = @all_services_array[0].count %>
                <% else %>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        CreateSlider("simple", "Total",   0, 144, 144);
                        CreateSlider("simple", "Design",  0, 64,  64);
                        CreateSlider("simple", "Develop", 0, 80,  80);
                    </script>
                <% end %>
            </div>

            <!-- Horizontal Rule to break the page up into sections -->
            <hr />

            <!-- Medium service type -->
            <label name="lblServiceType_Medium" class="biglbl servicetypeheading">Service Type: Medium</label>

            <div id="divServiceType_Medium" class="servicetypediv">
                <%= render :partial => 'project_plans/display_services', :locals => { :type_service => 'medium' } %>

                <%= render :partial => 'project_plans/add_service', :locals => { :service_type => 'medium' } %>

                <% if !@savedPlan.nil? %>
                    <% service_array_length = (@all_services_array[1].count - 1) %>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        <% if (service_array_length >= 0) %>
                            CreateSlider("medium", "Total",   145, 220, <%= @all_services_array[1][0].totalHours %>);
                            CreateSlider("medium", "Design",  0,   100, <%= @all_services_array[1][0].designHours %>);
                            CreateSlider("medium", "Develop", 0,   120, <%= @all_services_array[1][0].developHours %>);
                        <% else %>                      
                            CreateSlider("medium", "Total",   145, 220, 220);
                            CreateSlider("medium", "Design",  0,   100, 100);
                            CreateSlider("medium", "Develop", 0,   120, 120);
                        <% end %>
                    </script>

                    <% (0..service_array_length).each do |i| %>
                        <% service = @all_services_array[1][i] %>

                        <%= render(:partial => 'project_plans/new_service',
                                   :locals => { :type_service => 'medium', :type_count => (i + 1),
                                                :service_name => service.name, :start_date => service.startDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
                                                :end_date => service.endDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
                                                :design_endDate => service.design_endDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), :priority => service.priority,
                                                :should_display_button => ((i != service_array_length) ? 'false' : 'true') }) %>
                    <% end %>

                    <% session[:medium] = @all_services_array[1].count %>
                <% else %>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        CreateSlider("medium", "Total",   145, 220, 220);
                        CreateSlider("medium", "Design",  0,   100, 100);
                        CreateSlider("medium", "Develop", 0,   120, 120);
                    </script>
                <% end %>
            </div>

            <!-- Horizontal Rule to break the page up into sections -->
            <hr />

            <!-- Complex service type -->
            <label name="lblServiceType_Complex" class="biglbl servicetypeheading">Service Type: Complex</label>

            <div id="divServiceType_Complex" class="servicetypediv">
                <%= render :partial => 'project_plans/display_services', :locals => { :type_service => 'complex' } %>

                <%= render :partial => 'project_plans/add_service', :locals => { :service_type => 'complex' } %>

                <% if !@savedPlan.nil? %>
                    <% service_array_length = (@all_services_array[2].count - 1) %>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        <% if (service_array_length >= 0) %>
                            CreateSlider("complex", "Total",   221, 295, <%= @all_services_array[2][0].totalHours %>);
                            CreateSlider("complex", "Design",  0,   135, <%= @all_services_array[2][0].designHours %>);
                            CreateSlider("complex", "Develop", 0,   160, <%= @all_services_array[2][0].developHours %>);
                        <% else %>                      
                            CreateSlider("complex", "Total",   221, 295, 295);
                            CreateSlider("complex", "Design",  0,   135, 135);
                            CreateSlider("complex", "Develop", 0,   160, 160);
                        <% end %>
                    </script>

                    <% (0..service_array_length).each do |i| %>
                        <% service = @all_services_array[2][i] %>

                        <%= render(:partial => 'project_plans/new_service',
                                   :locals => { :type_service => 'complex', :type_count => (i + 1),
                                                :service_name => service.name, :start_date => service.startDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
                                                :end_date => service.endDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
                                                :design_endDate => service.design_endDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), :priority => service.priority,
                                                :should_display_button => ((i != service_array_length) ? 'false' : 'true') }) %>
                    <% end %>

                    <% session[:complex] = @all_services_array[2].count %>
                <% else %>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        CreateSlider("complex", "Total",   221, 295, 295);
                        CreateSlider("complex", "Design",  0,   135, 135);
                        CreateSlider("complex", "Develop", 0,   160, 160);
                    </script>
                <% end %>
            </div>

            <!-- Horizontal Rule to break the page up into sections -->
            <hr />

            <!-- Incremental service type -->
            <label name="lblServiceType_Incremental" class="biglbl servicetypeheading">Service Type: Incremental</label>

            <div id="divServiceType_Incremental" class="servicetypediv">
                <%= render :partial => 'project_plans/display_services', :locals => { :type_service => 'incremental' } %>

                <%= render :partial => 'project_plans/add_service', :locals => { :service_type => 'incremental' } %>

                <% if !@savedPlan.nil? %>
                    <% service_array_length = (@all_services_array[3].count - 1) %>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        <% if (service_array_length >= 0) %>
                            CreateSlider("incremental", "Total",   0, 40, <%= @all_services_array[3][0].totalHours %>);
                            CreateSlider("incremental", "Design",  0, 40, <%= @all_services_array[3][0].designHours %>);
                            CreateSlider("incremental", "Develop", 0, 40, <%= @all_services_array[3][0].developHours %>);
                        <% else %>                      
                            CreateSlider("incremental", "Total",   0, 40, 40);
                            CreateSlider("incremental", "Design",  0, 20, 20);
                            CreateSlider("incremental", "Develop", 0, 20, 20);
                        <% end %>
                    </script>

                    <% (0..service_array_length).each do |i| %>
                        <% service = @all_services_array[3][i] %>

                        <%= render(:partial => 'project_plans/new_service',
                                   :locals => { :type_service => 'incremental', :type_count => (i + 1),
                                                :service_name => service.name, :start_date => service.startDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
                                                :end_date => service.endDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
                                                :design_endDate => service.design_endDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), :priority => service.priority,
                                                :should_display_button => ((i != service_array_length) ? 'false' : 'true') }) %>
                    <% end %>

                    <% session[:incremental] = @all_services_array[3].count %>
                <% else %>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        CreateSlider("incremental", "Total",   0, 40, 40);
                        CreateSlider("incremental", "Design",  0, 20, 20);
                        CreateSlider("incremental", "Develop", 0, 20, 20);
                    </script>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Horizontal Rule to break the page up into sections -->
        <hr />

        <!-- Resources section -->
        <label name="lblResources" class="biglbl servicetypeheading">Resources</label>

        <div id="resources" class="servicetypediv">
            <%= render :partial => 'project_plans/add_resource' %>

            <% if !@savedPlan.nil? %>
                <% resource_array_length = (@all_resources_array.count - 1) %>

                <% (0..resource_array_length).each do |i| %>
                    <% resource = @all_resources_array[i] %> 

                    <%= render(:partial => 'project_plans/new_resource',
                               :locals => { :type_count => (i + 1), :resource_name => resource.name, :start_date => resource.startDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
                                            :end_date => resource.endDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), :resource_type => resource.resourceType,
                                            :should_display_button => ((i != resource_array_length) ? 'false' : 'true') }) %>
                <% end %>

                <% session[:rescount] = @all_resources_array.count %>
            <% end %>
        </div>

        <!-- Horizontal Rule to break the page up into sections -->
        <hr />

        <div>
            <p class="biglbl">Notes:</p>

            <textarea class="span6 textarea-spacing" name="txtNotes" rows="5"
                      placeholder="Enter any notes here"><%= if !@savedPlan.nil?; @savedPlan.notes; end %></textarea>

            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-project-plan" value="<%= session[:accessType] %> Project Plan" type="button"
                   onclick="ValidateForm($('#frmvariableplan'))">
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div class="fixed projectmode">
    <%= form_tag({:controller => 'project_plans', :action => 'render_plan' },
                 { :multipart => true, :id => 'frmfixedplan', :name => 'frmfixedplan', :class => 'form-inline' }) do %>
        <input id="fixed_project_mode" name="projectmode" value="fixed" type="hidden">

        <div class="row proj-start-end-date-div">
            <div class="span4">
                <%= label_tag :projname, "Project Name", :class => 'project_date_label biglbl biglbl-spacing' %>
                <input class="proj-start-end-date input-spacing" name="projname" type="text">
            </div>

            <div class="span4">
                <%= label_tag :projstartdate, "Start Date", :class => 'project_date_label biglbl biglbl-spacing' %>
                <input class="proj-start-end-date input-spacing datepicker read_only_input" name="projstartdate" type="text" readonly="true">
            </div>

            <div class="span4">
                <%= label_tag :projenddate, "End Date", :class => 'project_date_label biglbl biglbl-spacing' %>
                <input class="proj-start-end-date" name="projenddate" type="text" readonly="true">
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<% if session[:accessType] == "View" %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        disableForm($('#frmvariableplan'));
    </script>
<% end %>
```

---

* **THE ANSWER *****

**I've finally figured it out!**

The issue was something that normally wouldn't cross my mind: the authenticity token. Because my JavaScript function disabled basically every element on the form, the authenticity checks that Rails implements by default were also disabled. This means that they wouldn't be submitted to the server upon POST request, and Rails would interpret the incorrect/missing authenticity token as a fraudulent request. In this situation, the session information is cleared out in order to protect your application.

Imagine a website like Twitter or Facebook, where you can log in, post content, etc. Since the user's login is stored as a session, it only makes sense to clear out the entire session if a fraudulent request is made because this will effectively log out the user.

In order to resolve the issue, I simply enabled the two authenticity input boxes using JavaScript after disabling all elements on the form:

```
$(document.getElementsByName("utf8")[0]).attr('disabled', false);
$(document.getElementsByName("authenticity_token")[0]).attr('disabled', false);
```

That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Before you worry about the session hash being cleared, is there a very good reason why you're using a form in your show view?  You can display that information much more easily in other ways - could you put the show file you're talking about into your question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, dax. I use a form in my show view because it presents the user with the same interface that he/she is used to. The form also sends the same request to the server as the other modes (create, edit). I need to send this request to get the output of the form. However, you do have a point that the information could be displayed much more easily. I've included the show file as an edit to my question.

Comment: glad you got it figured out!